# Find the limiting value of x in the case when b < a

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> In a chemical reaction, substance X is created from substances A and
>   B.
>
> A + B → X.
>
> Assuming that the rate of production of X is proportional to the concentrations
>   of A and B at any given time t, the reaction can be described by the ODE
>
> $$\frac{dx}{dt}= \alpha(a − x)(b − x)$$
>
> where $\alpha \gt 0$ is a constant; $x(t)$ is the concentration of X at time $t$; $a$ is the initial concentration of A; and $b$ is the initial concentration of B.
>
> Find the limiting value of $x$ in the case when $b \lt a$ and explain
>   the physical significance of the limiting value.

I don't quite understand the term limiting value; would it be when $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$ or would I need to find a solution of the equation and find the limit as $t$ goes to infinity?
I am very confused...

Comment: I might be wrong, but as I understand it, you first have to solve the ODE for $x(t)$ and then find the value of $t$ that optimizes $x(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "find a solution of the equation and find the limit as $t$ goes to infinity". Incidentally, you can check that the solutions of the differential equation can be written in the form
$$
x(t)=\frac{b -a e^{(b-a) (\alpha t+c)}}{1-e^{(b-a) (\alpha t+c)}}
$$
for some $c$. Naturally, this predicts that $x(t)\to b$ when $t\to+\infty$ since we will run out of B.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\frac{dx}{dt} > 0$ if $x < b$ and $\frac{dx}{dt} < 0$ if $b < x < a$. Thus, if we assume an initial condition of $x(0) = 0$, it follows that $x(t) \to b$ as $t \to \infty$. This is a stable equilibrium solution.

Indeed, this should intuitively make sense from what we know in chemistry. As $b < a$, we know that substance $B$ is the [limiting reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_reagent) in the reaction (representing the bottleneck). It will be totally consumed during the reaction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the limiting value is what happens when $t \to \infty$. In this case you will reach a state of equilibrium with $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$. Then we have
$0 = \alpha(a-x)(b-x),$ that is $(x-a)(x-b)=0,$ since $\alpha \neq 0$. Thus $x=a$ or $x=b$. Since $b < a$, we conclude that $x = b$ (do you see why?)